# Related searches / people also searched for

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs

Currently in SO q & a when looking at a question you have related questions.  Can we do something similar in Jobs such that there are two panels / divs that show **related searches** (after you search a key word in jobs) as well as **people also searched for**.

The right side of the page where we feature a company has plenty of room to add this information.

Comment: This seems like it might create quite a bit of admin overhead (to eliminate bad associations, impolite search terms, etc.).  Remember, companies *pay* to get on here, they probably will expect some level of curation if this stuff ends up on their company page.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - The company has nothing to do with this, this is at the UI level of the candidate.

Comment: So if I search for Palantir and it tells me "People also searched for 'spyware'," how will that make Palantir feel?

Comment: How would palantir know?  And what is the relationship of spyware to Palantir?

Comment: If I work in Palantir HR, I might want to know what the candidate experience is like on sites that I send money to.  I key in "Palantir" and am returned a bunch of my job postings plus some other stuff.  If you don't know the relationship between Palantir and spyware, well, we never had this conversation.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We recently pushed something similar out. While viewing a job listing, you will now see a "You might also like..." section in the side bar with similar jobs.

We don't have "people also searched for" and I'm not sure that we'll create that *exact* solution however displaying the best job matches for developers is the goal so we'll keep this in mind.[image]